# In Play2.x how can I uglify js templates

Tags: playframework, production-environment

In one of my Play2.4 application (Scala), I have JS files that are generated via Twirl (the template engine) so I can use internal variables.

Is there a way these JS files can be minified once in Prod?

Comment: Are you using Java or Scala?

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can try is creating a custom Play Filter which uses a Java-based compressor for JavaScript.  Here is an example of one that I found:
https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.java

Another way is using a template which passes the generated JS into the above class.

Comment: Nice approach but I was looking for something less hacky, a play embedded option that you could setup in build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify) for that. First you need to add the plugin to your plugins.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
```

Next, modify your project build.sbt file and enable sbt-web:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

Declare the uglify sbt-web plugin execution:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify)
```

This will make the build to uglify your javascript assets when making a release package (using activator dist). 
If you want to test the uglify in you dev environment use this line instead:

```
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify)
```

Finally, you need to modify the way the javascript assets are loaded in the twirl templates. Instead of @routes.Assets.at("something.js"), now use @routes.Assets.versioned("something.js")

Comment: I think this works if you work with files in `public`. I have Twirl templates so I can't call them with `versioned`

Comment: This works with javascripts in the app/assets or the public folder. It should work with twirl templates if you are loading them with @routes.Assets.at()

Comment: it doesn't. See error  `type mismatch;`
`[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.Call`
`[error]  required: controllers.Assets.Asset`
`[error]   <script type="text/javascript"` `src="@routes.Assets.versioned(routes.Application.js)"></script>`

Comment: You're right, it probably won't work. I don't think mixing twirl templates and .js files is a good ideia, anyway. That might be a bit hard to mantain when the app grows.